# Problem with using mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous and convex function over $[a,b]$ which has first derivative over $[a,b]$. prove that:
$f'(a)\leq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \leq f'(b)$

I know that  this is easy through mean value theorem, however, I think that the function should be twice differentiable and the second derivative should be continuous, otherwise I think the result above is not true.

Am I right? If yes, could you give me a counterexample? I tried but I didn't find anyone.

Comment: convex and differentiable implies the derivative is increasing.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah but there are some functions which they are convex and differentiable but they don't have second derivative, consider $|x|^(3/2)$

Comment: I did not speak about second derivative.

Comment: but for proving the theorem we should apply mean value theorem for second derivative.

Comment: Perhaps you should show your argument using the MVT.

Comment: @RosalynMcClellan : In MathJax and in LaTeX, $|x|^{3/2}$ is coded as `|x|^{3/2}`. $\qquad$

Comment: I suspect this can be done without the mean value theorem.

Comment: Suppose one can show that $b\mapsto\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ for $b>a$ is nowhere decreasing. Then, since $\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \to f'(a) $ as $b\downarrow a,$ we would have $\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}>f'(a)$ for every $b>a.$ So suppose $a<b_1<b_2.$ Convexity implies that $\dfrac{f(b_1)-f(a)}{b_1-a}<\dfrac{f(b_2)-f(b_1)}{b_2-b_1}.$ I expect one can go on from there to finish it off without anything more about limits or derivatives. $\qquad$

Comment: Are you sure you have quoted the problem correctly? If you take $a = -1$, $b = 1$ and $f(x) = 1 - \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ (so the graph of $f$ is an upward facing semicircle). Then $f$ is continuous and convex on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$, but $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ don't exist.

Comment: @RobArthan My bad, $f$ is differentiable over $[a,b]$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f$ is convex and $f'(a),f'(b)$ exist.

Fix $x\in (a,b)$.

Then letting $t={\large{\frac{x-a}{b-a}}}$, we have
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{align*}
&0 < t < 1\\[4pt]
&x=(1-t)a+tb\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
hence by convexity of $f$ we have
$$
f(x)\le (1-t)f(a)+tf(b)=f(a)+t\bigl(f(b)-f(a)\bigr)
$$
hence
\begin{align*}
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}
&\le
\frac{t\bigl(f(b)-f(a)\bigr)}{x-a}
\\[4pt]
&=
\bigl(f(b)-f(a)\bigr)
\left(
\frac{t}{x-a}
\right)
\\[4pt]
&=
\bigl(f(b)-f(a)\bigr)
\left(
\frac{1}{b-a}
\right)
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence from
$$
f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}
$$
it follows that
$$
f'(a)\le \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$
as was to be shown.

The inequality
$$
f'(b)\ge \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$
can be proved analogously.